# Impact of a mutable member on a complete const object and UB

Tags: c++, c++20

A complete const object cannot be replaced per [basic.life](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8.3). Placement new will result in UB. This is a complete const object:

```
struct A {int i{};};
const A cco;
```

However, this, because it isn't a complete const object and only the subobject is const, may be replaced as of c++20:

```
struct A {const int i{};};
A o;
```

But what about this?

```
struct A {int i{}; mutable int mi{};};
const A o;
```

It looks like it's a complete const object. And the [standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.stc#9): *The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a const specifier applied to the containing class object*.

It would thus seem that if it *nullifies the containing class object* then `A` is no longer const and it would no longer be a *complete const object*. So I decided to investigate what happens when I try to alter the object using a `consteval` function as well as run-time evaluation:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i{ 1 };
    mutable int mi{ 2 };
};

const A a;

consteval int foo()
{
    const A a;
    std::construct_at(&a, A{ 8,9 });
    return a.i;
}

int main()
{
    std::construct_at(&a, A{ 8,9 });
    std::cout << a.i << '\n';

    constexpr int cexpr_test = foo();
    std::cout << cexpr_test << '\n';
}
```

Both compile time and run time results in MSVC produce 8's which indicates the contents were replaced. However, this doesn't mean UB doesn't exist. Expanding this to [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T3vde53eY) shows that the modification also succeeded in GCC. But not in CLANG's run-time evaluation. Curiously, CLANG's `consteval` did modify the object.

So the question: Is it UB because the object remains a *complete const object* in spite of the standard's wording or is it UB and just wasn't picked up by any of the compiler's `consteval` at compile time?

Comment: You should call `a.~A()` before reusing the storage in `construct_at` unless you *do not rely on any side effect the destructor has*. Meaning memory and other resources leaking if A isn't trivial.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow calling a destructor is not needed  for types that are trivially destructable.

Comment: Did you skip over the *if A isn't trivial* in my comment? It's good practice to call the destructor even if A is trivial though. I know you don't have to but in real code it's easy for A to grow and stop being trivially destructible and then have fun finding all the places you forgot to call the destructor.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  Agree it's good practice. Was trying to keep it short.  Thought you might be saying the example had side effects.

Comment: I was hoping clang consteval would change with the destructor but no change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[dcl.stc#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.stc#9) says:

> [Note 4: The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a `const` specifier applied to the containing class object and **permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is `const`** ([basic.type.qualifier], [dcl.type.cv]).
> — end note]

(emphasis mine)

This means that a modification of only the mutable class member is permitted and if we try to modify any other non-mutable data members of such a `const` object the result will still be **undefined** as *"the rest of the object is const"*.

In your example this means that only the `mi` mutable data member is permitted to be modified for a `const A` object and if we try to modify `i` the result will be undefined.

Comment: Sure the non mutable i remains const but that alone doesn't make it non-modifieable by placement new since it's a subobject. And the containing object's `const` is nullified. Perhaps what they meant was that it was nullified only in respect to the mutable element and that the object remains a "complete const object". That would make sense and is likely the intent.

Comment: @doug Yes, that is what my reading of [dcl.stc#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.stc#9) is since they specifically say that *"permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is `const`."* and as you said it makes sense.

Comment: Would have been clearer if they just said the mutable permits that member to be modified even though the container is const. But hey, it's c++.

Comment: @doug TBH it seems  clear enough to me. But it happens many times that what is clear/obvious to one may or maynot be obvious to some other person. Agreed that it's c++ that we're talking about and given that it is such a vast language these things are bound to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the standard that is in a "Note" (such as [dcl.stc]/4, which you cited) is non-normative text. That is, the words have no actual force as far as the standard is concerned. You have to track down the actual part of the standard that explains more directly what `mutable` does.

The phrase "complete const object" merely refers to an object that has the properties of being both "complete" and "const". It is a complete object, per [intro.object]/2. It is a "const" object per [basic.type.qualifier]/1.1. Therefore it is "complete const" (or "const complete" as [basic.life]/11 calls it) and must follow the rules of such an object.

If those rules don't include affordances for `mutable` (and they don't), then `mutable` members are irrelevant.

Comment: That was the only thing I found in the standard decribing the behavior. Good point on the note being non-normative. That's probably the best argument that the object is a complete const object even with the mutable.

Comment: Notes might be non-normative but they are still important. They convey the intent of how the things should work which, in the end, is the only thing that matters.

Comment: @ixSci: But their exact wording is not to be taken at face value. This question is primarily about the exact wording of what it says `mutable` means. Conveying intent is useful, but it cannot be taken the same way as you would a normative statement of behavior.